# Web scraping with pyppeteer, but site is blocking me

Tags: python, web-scraping, puppeteer, pyppeteer

I'm trying to web scraping to get some coupom values applyed in a product in site, but it keeps blocking me. I've already tried to use proxy with my country IP, changing headers, searching for some "id" to access, like some aws auths, with and without anonymous page, headless true, false and nothing works, here what i tried.

```py
    args = [
        '--start-maximized',
        '--disable-extensions',
        '--hide-scrollbars',
        '--disable-bundled-ppapi-flash',
        '--mute-audio',
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
        '--disable-gpu',
        '--proxy-server='+self.PROXY_HOST+':'+str(self.PROXY_PORT)
    ]

    #browser = await launch(headless=False, ignoreHTTPSErrors=True, userDataDir='./tmp', options={'args': args})
    browser = await launch(headless=False, options={'args': args})
    browser_context = await browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext()
    page = await browser_context.newPage()
    await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Safari/537.36')
    await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
        "X-Frame-Options": "GOFORIT"
    })

    await page.setViewport({
        'width': 1366,
        'height': 768
    })

    await page.authenticate({'username': self.PROXY_USER, 'password': self.PROXY_PASS})

    await page.setRequestInterception(True)
        async def intercept(request):
            if "origem=PD" in request.url:
                    await request.continue_({
                        "headers": {
                            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36', 
                            'Accept' : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8', 
                            'Accept-Language' : 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
                            'Accept-Encoding' : 'gzip', 
                            'DNT' : '1',
                            'Connection' : 'close'
                        }
                    })
                else:
                    await request.continue_()

    # intercept links
    page.on('request', lambda req: asyncio.ensure_future(intercept(req)))

    # wait for navigation
    await asyncio.wait([page.goto(url, {'waitUntil': 'networkidle2'}), page.waitForNavigation()])

    # get content
    content = await page.content()
```

[image: extra blocking]

Comment: Some websites detect selenium and puppeteer or controlled browsers. Try using [Chrome DevTools Protocols](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/), and you can use [pychrome](https://github.com/fate0/pychrome) to sent commands. It has many limitations are more research needed, but it worked on one of my projects when my bot was getting block.

Answer (score 1):

There are several browser parameters that can be detected by site to determine if browser is automated or not. You can test your pyppeteer browser over here - https://bot.sannysoft.com/

Of course, it can by bypassed :) There is library for this - https://github.com/MeiK2333/pyppeteer_stealth